# ajax request return code 400, bad request

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-status-code-400, jqxhr

hey i have a ajax request like

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://solr.plunq.id:8984/solr/'+ url_Category +'/select',
        data: {q: "*:*", start: offset, rows: limit, wt: 'json', indent:'true', omitHeader:'true',fq:'{!geofilt%20pt='+ latitude +','+ longitude +'%20sfield=latlon%20d=5}'},
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType : 'json'
    }).done(function (result) {});
```

why return 400 bad request? But when i open in browser the site its fine
:( pls help

Comment: What does the final URL look like?

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be using POST, since the data doesn't look like GET data. Is it? Does jQuery's ajax massage data into ?prefixed KVPs when you make the call like that?